# Compatibility of countable intersection and limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

Suppose $(x_n)_{n \in \Bbb{N}} \subset \Bbb{R}$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Also $x_n \geq x_{n+1}$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$.

Consider $\bigcap_{n \in \Bbb{N}} (-\infty, x_n]$. Intuitively I think that this intersection should equal $(-\infty, x]$, but I can't seem to prove this formally. I tried using the "Sandwich-Lemma" but I'm not sure it even applies (due to $-\infty$ on the lefthand side). Is the statement even true? When I attempt to prove it I can't bring together the definitions of limits and intersections.

Another example would be $\bigcap_{n \in \Bbb{N}}(-\infty,x_n] = \emptyset$ for $x_n \rightarrow -\infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Any general tips on how to approach proving statements like these and references on similar identities would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can show that $x_n\geq x$ for all $n$, which mean $(-\infty,x]$ is a subset of each $(-\infty,x_n]$, which gets you that $(-\infty,x]$ is a subset of the intersection.

Next, suppose $y\notin(-\infty,x]$. Use that the $x_n$ converge to $x$ to show that there's some $(-\infty,x_n]$ that $y$ isn't in.

Here the logic is showing that anything in $(-\infty,x]$ is in the intersection, and anything NOT in $(-\infty,x]$ isn't in the intersection. You could alternatively show two sets are equal by showing that each is a subset of the other. (That's the core idea here, but it is using a contrapositive for one of the implications.)

So for your second example, if you assume there is a $y$ in the intersection you get a contradiction, which means it must not have any elements i.e. it's the emptyset.